# Pause Background music on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm using a HTML5 audio tag to play some background music, and I would like the music to pause when the user scrolls past a certain point, and start again when the user scrolls back to the top... Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following example (plain javascript, no jQuery) pauses the audio if you scrolls the scrollbar 350px down (and plays it again when you get back to the top);

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 350 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350) {
        document.getElementById("player").pause(); 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("player").play();  
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: tomato;  
}
```

```html
<audio controls autoplay loop id=player>
  <source src="http://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary_download?vid=7fad087239069cd4" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p><p>scroll</p>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can bind to the `scroll` event to the window and trigger a foreach for `$('video')` and  call `pause` method when the limit and `play` when to offset is 0

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
   if (document.body.scrollTop === 0) $('video').forEach(function(){this.play()});
   if (document.body.scrollTop > 100) $('video').forEach(function(){this.pause()});
})
```